# How do I debug email delivery delays?

Tags: ubuntu, email, postfix

In order to get notified about some stuff going on on a server, I use simple mailutils command executed `@hourly` by `cron`:

```
cat $file | mail -s "Subject" $receivers
```

where `$receivers` is a list of a few email addresses.
Sometimes this solution works pretty smoothly, however, most of the time delivering to all email addresses delays for specific amount of time (~30 mins).
This delay time is always the same.

In `/var/log/mail.log` I can see a bunch of this kind of messages:

```
Mar 19 05:00:17 myserver postfix/smtp[21138]: connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2a00:1450:400b:c02::1b]:25: Network is unreachable
Mar 19 05:00:47 myserver postfix/smtp[21137]: connect to mail.global.sprint.com[207.46.163.247]:25: Connection timed out
Mar 19 05:00:47 myserver postfix/smtp[21138]: connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.24.27]:25: Connection timed out
Mar 19 05:01:17 myserver postfix/smtp[21137]: connect to mail.global.sprint.com[207.46.163.170]:25: Connection timed out
Mar 19 05:01:18 myserver postfix/smtp[21138]: connect to alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[173.194.65.27]:25: Connection timed out
Mar 19 05:01:18 myserver postfix/smtp[21138]: connect to alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2a00:1450:4013:c00::1b]:25: Network is unreachable
Mar 19 05:01:18 myserver postfix/smtp[21138]: connect to alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2a00:1450:4010:c0b::1b]:25: Network is unreachable
```

^ That repeats again after 10 minutes and next time successfully after 20 more minutes.
I would appreciate any ideas on what could cause this.

Comment: Did you ever resolve your issue? I have exactly the same problem, with exactly the same host names. I'm unable to forward email to gmail reliably. I am wondering if gmail is blocking or rate limiting my server. Emails are arriving eventually, though sometimes delayed by a few days. This all started after some messages about a full volume, although that is no longer an issue. My host is on AWS.

Comment: @DrewNoakes sorry mate, this has not been solved. The server admins ended up with prohibiting emailing to gmail host due to some security stuff so I never got back to this problem. Hope you'll find a solution!

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I'm considering reinstalling Postfix. Maybe something became corrupted when the volume was full.

Comment: I'm on AWS EC2 and they have some outbound mail limiting that may be the cause of the problem: https://aws.amazon.com/forms/ec2-email-limit-rdns-request

Comment: Might be a bit early to tell, but so far it looks as though making that request sorted the problem. I should point out, to others considering this solution, that I was getting _some_ email, but not all. Most people online seem to have an absolute connection issue, usually related to port 25 being blocked or so forth.

Answer (score 1):

Postfix can't connect to the gmail servers for some reason. This may be due to a firewall or routing issue. Try running the following command:

```
traceroute -T -p 25 <problematic server>
```

This should tell you exactly where the problem is located. Of course, if will only do so while the problem is happening, so you may need to try a few times...